# Paytm payments integration doesn't work on iOS 10

Tags: swift, ios10, payment, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm payments using Paytm_iOS_App_Kit

https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit

Using this example in link

https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/ios-sdk/

It works well in latest iOS versions. But in iOS 10, I am getting something went wrong error with debug details MID, ORDER_ID missing(the parameters are passed).

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using paytm's old ios sdk. Kindly use latest IOS SDK mentioned in all in one sdk document